# Is path of the inventory file accessible to playbooks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a hierarchy of inventories like this:

```
inventories
  foo
    foo1/hosts
    foo2/hosts
  bar
    bar1/hosts
    bar2/hosts
```

Normally, I invoke ansible with explicit full path:

```
ansible -i inventories/bar/bar1 ....
```

However, some of the playbooks can run on the combined inventories:

```
ansible -i inventories/bar ....
```

This joins the multiple `hosts` files together, just as I want. However, I do not see a way for the tasks and templates to discern, which particular sub-inventory(ies) the host belongs to.

Is there a way to know about this? Ideally, a host would belong to group(s) based on the inventory file(s) it is listed in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is accessible. Ansible 2.3+ has the following two new [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables):

- `inventory_file`
- `inventory_dir`